# Intersects filter in WFS

Tags: wfs, intersection, getfeature

I try to use Intersects filter but I get an empty geometry in return. What did I miss in the syntax?

```
https://data.gov.au/geoserver/brimbank-stormwater-pits/wfs?request=GetFeature&version=1.0.0&typename=brimbank-stormwater-pits:ckan_3f07bec5_99c2_491f_8d39_b6061891ebb1&outputFormat=GML2&FILTER=<Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><Intersects><PropertyName>geom</PropertyName><gml:Polygon xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:4326"><gml:outerBoundaryIs><gml:LinearRing><gml:coordinates>144.7769072860001,-37.733680591086539 144.77697968000007,-37.733955687086535 144.78617369000006,-37.734882328086506 144.78611577600009,-37.734592753086503 144.7769072860001,-37.733680591086539</gml:coordinates></gml:LinearRing></gml:outerBoundaryIs></gml:Polygon></Intersects></Filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have omitted the required `service=WFS&` parameter and you have specified an unsupported CRS.

The 1.0.0 GetCapabilities response:

> https://data.gov.au/geoserver/brimbank-stormwater-pits/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&version1.0.0&

Shows that only `<DefaultCRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4283</DefaultCRS>` is supported, but you specified `EPSG:4326`

The following request works:

> https://data.gov.au/geoserver/brimbank-stormwater-pits/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.0.0&typename=brimbank-stormwater-pits:ckan_3f07bec5_99c2_491f_8d39_b6061891ebb1&outputFormat=GML2&FILTER=geom<gml:Polygon xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:4283">gml:outerBoundaryIsgml:LinearRinggml:coordinates144.7769072860001,-37.733680591086539 144.77697968000007,-37.733955687086535 144.78617369000006,-37.734882328086506 144.78611577600009,-37.734592753086503 144.7769072860001,-37.733680591086539</gml:coordinates></gml:LinearRing></gml:outerBoundaryIs></gml:Polygon>